# Mongodb deep nested array count

Tags: mongodb

I have this simple query:

```
[
    user:{
       _id     : ObjectId('5c058b38365f0e1a0848d61d')
       receipts:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    },
    user:{
       _id     : ObjectId('5c058b38365f0e1a0848ty56')
       receipts:[1,2,3,4,5]
    },
]
```

I need to get the array length for receipts, i tried few codes that i found online but none of them works, here the short one i have:

```
mongo.collection('links').aggregate([{
                $match:{_id: mongo.ObjectId('5c058b38365f0e1a0848d61d')},
                $project: {
                    usersCount: {
                        $size: "$users.receipts"
                    }
                }
}]).toArray(function(err, results) {
               console.log(err,results);
});
```

I get the error:

> **{ MongoError: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
>
> ```
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)   ok: 0,   errmsg:    'A pipeline stage specification object must
> ```
>
> contain exactly one field.',   code: 40323,   codeName:
>   'Location40323',   name: 'MongoError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} } null**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bunch of curly brackets which is why you are seeing the exception. The following should work:

```
[{
    $match: {
        _id: mongo.ObjectId('5c058b38365f0e1a0848d61d')
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "usersCount": { $size: "$data.user.receipts" }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, i wrote wrong query, it should be an array of users, i edited the question, thx:)

Comment: Your main problem is related to the missing curly brackets. If you can post one complete sample document I can also provide you the right query.

Comment: Yes i see it now, i guess i am getting old for that :(((  anyway thanks.